# How to get id to another page and make it show value based on id

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have already referred this post [How to get row ID in button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526475/how-to-get-row-id-in-button-click) but still can't make it load values and I do not know why.I'm pretty sure the id has been properly captured at profile.php. Below is my code:

```
hanj.php

  style type="text/css">
      .buttonize {
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #efefef;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 11px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
      }
     <?php require_once('Connections/conn.php');?>
    </style>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="600">
    <tr>
      <th>Vendor Id</th>
        <th>Kategori</th>
        <th>Nama Vendor</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Poskod</th>
        <th>Bandar</th>
         <th>Negeri</th>
         <th>No</th>
         <th>Email</th>
    </tr>



     <?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['profile']= $row ['v_id'];
    mysql_select_db ($database_conn,$conn);
    $query="SELECT v_id,type,companyName,address,code,city,state,contact,email FROM vendor";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['v_id'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['type'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['companyName'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['address'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['code'];
        echo "</td><td>";
         echo $row['city'];
        echo "</td><td>";
         echo $row['state'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['contact'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['email'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        print '<center><a href="profile.php?id='.$row['v_id'].'" class="buttonize">View</a></center>';
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>



 profile.php
    <?php require_once('Connections/conn.php'); ?>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Casado</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Pakej</th>
                      <th>Image</th>
                      <th>Harga</th>
                      <th>Vendor Id</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                  <?php
                  session_start();            
                   mysql_select_db ($database_conn,$conn);
                   $vid = $_SESSION['profile'];
                   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from item where v_id = '$vid' ") or die (mysql_error());
                   while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    ?>




                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $res['pakej'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.$res['image'].'" class="img-thumbnail">' ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $res['harga'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $res['v_id'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php }
                   ?>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
                </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

btw there is no syntax error

Comment: Instead of $_SESSION['profile'] use $_REQUEST['id'] in your profile.php and it should work.

Comment: thank you it worked man!!!!:)

Comment: Welcome brother . :)

Comment: can you explain a lil bit why use $_REQUEST

Comment: You are passing id through url (actually through get method). That is why you should get this id using $_GET method (or $_REQUEST method) . You have not set session variable in  hanj.php.But you were trying to get variable using session variable.That is why your code was not working.

Comment: Posting as an answer.So that we can validate. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$_SESSION['profile']` use `$_REQUEST['id']` in your `profile.php` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In profile.php use $_GET to reference the passed in 'id'. i.e
Replace the following line

```
$vid = $_SESSION['profile'];
```

with this one.

```
$vid = $_GET['id'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope I have try it..not working,still no values shown Mubashar Abbas

Comment: in profile.php on top try die($_GET['id']); to see if the id is there?

Answer (score 0):

this question is answered by Bikash Paul above where he suggest to change $_SESSION['profile'] to $_REQUEST['id']

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$vid = $_SESSION['profile'];` try `$vid = $_GET['profile'];`, if not works, then print_r($_GET) or print_r($_REQUEST) & show us the details